# Command to get the Helm version running on the windows OS

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I am  trying to get the helm version installed on my machines. I am getting this error: `helm is not recognized as internal or external command`

Comment: Is it in your PATH?

Answer (score 0):

First of all , did you check if helm has been installed in the machine you are running helm command ? If not installed try to install by following the instructions in the below URL :
https://helm.sh/docs/intro/install/

If helm has been installed can you verify if helm is in your PATH.
For Example, If you run echo $PATH in a mac computer or Unix/Linux OS it will show you if helm is in the path.

If helm is not in the path you can add it.
For Example: In a mac run a command similar (export PATH=$PATH:<helm_home>/bin) to the following

export PATH=$PATH:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/helm/3.8.2/bin

After that run the following command to check it recognizes helm

helm --help